# Android ListActivity: Title and SubTitle row

Tags: android, listactivity

Is there a SDK provided UI element to display a Title and Subtitle in a List's row? I can do it manually by creating a row XML, but want to do it so often in so may apps that wondered if there is a built-in way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2` layout, which shows the first item in large text and the second item in smaller text, is probably what you need.